# Dictionary Contain NSNull Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

Is there any way to detect that an `NSDictionary` contains a `NSNull` value?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful when you put `NSDictionary` and Swift in the same sentence. `NSDictionary` is a Foundation (i.e. Objective-C) reference type. Swift has its own native `Dictionary`, which is a value type (i.e. `struct`). You can bridge between the two easily, but it takes some CPU time doing so.

Now on to your question:

```
let dict: [String: Any] = [
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "age": NSNull()
]

let containsNSNull = dict.contains { $0.1 is NSNull } // true
```